# Ember-Cli SASS Settings

Tags: ember.js, sass, ember-cli

I am using `ember-cli-sass` instead of `broccoli-ruby-sass`

These are the steps i have done

```
npm install --save-dev ember-cli-sass

bower install --save foundation
```

I am getting this error in the console after i started the `ember server`

[image]

I don't understand why it says "File not found: /app/styles/app.scss"

i don't have any app.scss a part from

[image]

I am missing something in the configuration, what's the problem exactly?

I am using three sass file

```
_global.sass
_music.sass
_player.sass
```

i import them in app.sass

```
@import global
@import player
@import music
```

i was reading the https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-cli-sass and it says

Specify some include paths in config/environment.js:

```
ENV.sassOptions = {
  includePaths: [
    'bower_components/foundation/scss'
  ]
}
```

I am bit confused about these settings, i need some advices

Comment: You can always use `ember install:addon ember-cli-foundation-sass` and it will set you up to use `ember-cli-sass` and other goodies

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are getting the error because you may not have changed the name of your `app.css` file to `app.scss`

You your `app/styles` folder you should have a file called `app.scss` in that file I would put your imports

```
// app.scss
   @import 'foundation';
   @import 'global';
   @import 'player';
   @import 'music';
```

Then you need to add:

```
ENV.sassOptions = {
  includePaths: [
    'bower_components/foundation/scss'
  ]
}
```

To your `config/environment.js` like this:

```
module.exports = function(environment) {
  var ENV = {
    modulePrefix: 'test-sass',
    environment: environment,
    baseURL: '/',
    locationType: 'auto',
    sassOptions: {
      includePaths: [
        'bower_components/foundation/scss'
      ]
    },
    EmberENV: {
      FEATURES: {
   .....
```

If you are looking to use foundation in your ember-cli app use the ember-cli addon: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-cli-foundation-sass

Answer (score 0):

I think ember-cli-sass by default looks for sass files with extension .scss. If you are using file extension of .sass, you need to specify it in sassOptions.

```
ENV.sassOptions = {
  includePaths: [
    'bower_components/foundation/scss'
  ],
  extension: 'sass'
}
```

Check https://github.com/aexmachina/ember-cli-sass